# Envio de formulario y procesarlo en la misma página Wordpress - Redirección erronea

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios

Estoy intentando hacer una búsqueda mediante las funciones que proporciona wordpress pero me redirecciona continuamente a la página principal para mostrarme los resultados o si cambio la propiedad action y pongo "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" o "echo esc_url(get_permalink());
" me muestra error todo el rato.

El código es el siguiente:

```
                <section id="primary" class="content-area">
                    <main id="main" class="site-main">
                        <header class="page-header">
                            <h1 class="page-title">Búsqueda</h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="buscador">
                            <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>">
                                <div>
                                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Buscar:</label>
                                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Buscar..." />
                                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
                        // Procesar la búsqueda
                        $search_query = sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']);
                        $search_results = new WP_Query(array(
                            's' => $search_query,
                        ));

                        if ($search_results->have_posts()) :
                            while ($search_results->have_posts()) : $search_results->the_post();
                                get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'search');
                            endwhile;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        else :
                            echo '<p>No se encontraron resultados.</p>';
                        endif;
                    }
                    ?>
                </main>
            </section>
```

Alguien sabe por qué solamente muestra los posts en la página principal y cuando quiero que se procese en la misma página me muestra error página no encontrada?
Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradezco